# Is it possible to get ad group ids like keyword ids using adwords api?

Tags: api, google-ads-api, google-api-client

I am using google adwords api for keyword planner, I am able to get keyword ids using adwords api and I also wanna get ad group ids.
Does the actual api version support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike keywords, AdGroups are designed to be organized as you create them. Reorganizing your account after you've created several campaigns and ad groups wipes out all the valuable data you've accumulated, possibly affecting how your ads perform.

This is why there doesn't seem to be a tool to get ad group ids. However certain best practices are outlined in this [AdWords Help support articl](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6372655?hl=en)e.

The relevant part being

> A common method for organizing an AdWords account is to organize with
>   a category or business goal in mind. For many businesses, the way your
>   website is structured is a good place to start, where each ad group
>   representing a different page or category on your site.  Ad groups can
>   help ensure that your ads are relevant to your keywords. For example,
>   for your camera campaign, you may want to create separate ads for
>   digital cameras and compact cameras. You can create ad groups for each
>   type of camera, each with its own set of focused, relevant keywords.
>   For your television campaign, you can also create an ad group for each
>   type of television you sell, such as flat screen and plasma TVs.